# How do I calculate the conditional expectation?

Tags: probability, statistics

How do I find a conditional expectation, $E(Y|X)$ for:

$f_{XY}(x,y)=2e^{-(x+y)}$ for $0<x<y$.

I researched that the formula for a conditional expectation is:

$E(Y|X) = \Sigma yf_{Y|X}(y|x)$

And I have already calculated the conditional density as:

$f_{Y|X}(y|x) = e^{x-y}$ for $0<x<y$

Thus,

$E(Y|X) = \Sigma ye^{x-y}$ for $0<x<y$

Comment: You have nor written $f_{y|x}$ correctly.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy sorry can you clarify what you mean that is is incorrect ?

Comment: You have to specify that the conditional density is $e^{x-y}$ for $0<x<y$. Leaving out the condition $0<x<y$ will lead to wrong answers.

Comment: I have re-edited the question for a more correct explanation. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional density you have found is for $0<x<y$. $E(Y|X)=\int_x^{\infty} ye^{x-y} dy$. Integrate by parts to find the exact value.

Comment: I have calculated the answer to be x + 1 but am unsure if I made a mistake with the integral

Comment: The answer is $x+1$.

Answer (score 0):

First your density function $f_{Y\mid X=x}$ is wrong. Anyway, suppose it's true : what you computed (if you replace of cours $\sum_{y}$ by $\int_{\mathbb R}$) is $$\mathbb E[Y\mid X=x].$$
But $$\mathbb E[Y\mid X]=\int_{\mathbb R}ye^{X-y}\,\mathrm d y=e^X\int_{\mathbb R}ye^{-y}\,\mathrm d y.$$

Comment: Ahh.. so I evaluate the integral by way of integration by parts ?

Comment: Yes indeed.$\ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: OP has written the conditional density wrongly. The integral is not over the whole line.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Yes indeed. I'll let him adapt this point.

Comment: @Surb sorry, isn’t the density function $\frac{f(x,y)}{f_X(x)} = \frac{2e^{-(x+y)}}{2e^{-2x}} = e^{x-y}$?

Comment: @i9-9980XE : Notice that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)\neq e^{-(x+y)}$ but it's equal to $e^{-(x+x)}\boldsymbol 1_{\{0<x<y\}}(x,y)$.

Comment: Yep, I have edited the question correctly